# Exception: Error getting value from 'Position' on 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.MD5Stream'

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, base64

I am facing this exception

```
Error getting value from 'Position' on 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.MD5Stream'.
```

when trying to read file from aws s3 bucket.

Here is my c# code

```
    try
    {
    var s3ObjectPath = $"users/{email.Id}/emailattachments/{item.AttachedFileName}";
    var ifExists = await this.Exists(s3ObjectPath);
    if (ifExists)
    {
    Stream attachment = await s3Client.GetObjectStreamAsync(attachmentS3BucketName, s3ObjectPath, dicData);
    Attachment att = new Attachment(attachment, item.AttachedFileName);
    attachments.Add(att);
    }
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

However this is working sometimes. I searched everywhere but didn't find solution.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: Stream attachment = await s3Client.GetObjectStreamAsync(attachmentS3BucketName, s3ObjectPath, dicData);

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an issue with how [Streams](https://msazure.visualstudio.com/One/_build/results?buildId=55952516&view=results) work. When you open a Stream you are not actually getting the content of the file, rather you are opening a connection enabling you to access the data.

The error you got is returned when your code is trying to access the stream but doesn't have the ability to do so (a connection being lost / no appropriate credentials in the code accessing the stream or any other reason).

The solution is either to solve the underlaying issue and make sure your code still as access to the Stream or to just read from the stream and return a string rather than a stream

The code addition would look something like this:

```
...
Stream attachment = await s3Client.GetObjectStreamAsync(attachmentS3BucketName, s3ObjectPath, dicData);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(attachment);
string attachmentText = reader.ReadToEnd();
Attachment att = new Attachment(attachmentText, item.AttachedFileName);
attachments.Add(att);
```